# Javascript - Higher order functions, callbacks, returning, scope chain - I could use some assistance, see example pleas

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I really could use some help in understanding how this all works. Please bare with since I am a disabled learner who sometimes can not grasp basic concepts like other people. I have tried looking it up, searching Google, and Chatgpt for answers, but I seem to have a problem with closure I believe it called.

```
 function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
    return num => callback1(num) || callback2(num)
   
}


function filterArray(array, callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (callback(array[i],i, array)) newArray.push(array[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
const arrOfNums = [10, 35, 105, 9];
const integerSquareRoot = n => Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
const over100 = n => n > 100;
const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
console.log(filterArray(arrOfNums, intSqRtOrOver100)); // should log: [105, 9]
```

So, what I do not understand is the value/values being sent to eitherCallback and how the arguments work.

So first filterArray has 2 parameters, arrOfNums and intSqRtOrOver100
So I was able to figure out a lot of problems like that intSqRtOrOver100 is a function just a variable, a function expression, however, that is not hoisted so filterArray would go first.

arrOfNums would be the array, and intSqRtOrOver100 would invoke intSqRtOrOver100 the function,

**First Question/Issue:** intSqRtOrOver100 is the function calling eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);? So intSqRtOrOver100 would take not arguments, however, filterArray is passing it iteration of referenced index in the array passing the value to the callback which is intSqRtOrOver100. So it would be 10 passed to intSqRtOrOver100?

Yet, there are 3 arguments being sent to intSqRtOrOver100?

**Second Question/Issue:**  When  intSqRtOrOver100 is invoked by the callback,  intSqRtOrOver100 is calling eitherCallback with two parameters, so the two parameters are functions passed in as arguments which I understand, however, when intSqRtOrOver100 is invoked, those two parameters are not being passed arguments since they are functions yet, somehow it is being sent an element from the array?

**Third Question/Issue:** So eitherCallback has two functions and is created by intSqRtOrOver100 invoked, I am passing an element from the array and somehow 3 things from filterArray? Also, no arguments are being sent since they are functions, then inside of the function I am using a return function I guess the name if "num", however, how can Callback1(num) exist? Nothing is declared as num except itself. Changing the parameter name defaults to an error. I understand the  about it being true and condition of it but, not how Callback1 is being called with "num" itself and how come the index, plus two others are being passed into it yet, I can not access the newArray, i or the array inside of eitherCallback, yet shouldn't filterArray be the higher order function and since it's the parent, should I be able to access it values?

Please, I have really tried for over 8 hours to understand this. I do understand some of it, but, since this is my first time asking for help, I was nervous about asking and hope I got it to come out right. If you could explain it to me simply and slowly because I am not quite understanding and I really want to learn this concept if possible. Thank you so much for your time.

Searched:

Google
Stackoverflow
Videos
ChatGPT
Chegg
Various Websites
Digital Ocean
Youtube

Comment: Please only ask one issue per question.

Comment: I'm Sorry, I was not thinking about that. I will do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a little try to explain. The core that you are missing is the thing that is happening here:

```
function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
  return num => callback1(num) || callback2(num);
}
```

This function takes 2 parameters, `callback1` and `callback2`, which supposed to be a functions. And returns a function which takes 1 argument named (num) and executes 2 closure captured functions (`callback1` and `callback2`) with that `num`. Basically, it is an alternative to this:

```
function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
  function fn(num) {
    return callback1(num) || callback2(num);
  }
  return fn;
}
```

Now about this section:

```
const integerSquareRoot = n => Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
const over100 = n => n > 100;
const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
```

Here you are declaring 2 arrow functions, `integerSquareRoot` and `over100`. They both are functions that take 1 argument. Equivalent:

```
function integerSquareRoot(n) {
  return Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
}
function over100(n) {
  return n > 100;
}
const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
```

Here you are calling `eitherCallback` with 2 arguments. Basically you are passing the references to those functions, and they are "wired" now, [closure captured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).
So, now, `intSqRtOrOver100` is the `fn` returned from `eitherCallback`, which has `integerSquareRoot` as `callback1` and `over100` as `callback2`. And it does take 1 argument, which is (num).

Now about this section:

```
function filterArray(array, callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (callback(array[i],i, array)) newArray.push(array[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Especially the `callback(array[i], i, array)` - why it is called with 3 parameters - just conventionally, I guess, inspired by [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), for example, which also accept a callback function with 3 parameters. But still, you can pass a callback function that takes 1 parameter only and it is absolutelly normal. You can easilly check what is passed to your callback by:

```
function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
  return (num) => {
    console.log(num);
    return callback1(num) || callback2(num);
  };
}
```

or

```
function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
  return (num, index, array) => {
    console.log(num, index, array);
    return callback1(num) || callback2(num);
  };
}
```

So, to summarize:

Q1 and Q2 - `intSqRtOrOver100` is the function that takes 1 parameter (num) and is internally wired to `integerSquareRoot` and `over100` via closure.

Q3 You are passing 3 parameters to `intSqRtOrOver100` hovewer `intSqRtOrOver100` utilizes only 1st parameter, rest ones are ignored.

Comment: I guess I did my best here and I hope it will help you at least partially, probably I will get some downvotes due to the size of the answer, but anyway, good luck with your studies! And ask smaller questions next time please :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not thinking about that, that I forgot to break up the question. I will in the future do that. 

You did a fantastic job in answering my question. I am still reading through it and will write it down. You put in so much effort into this answer, Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.